# Is it possible to make CSS exclusively for mobile devices in an Email?

Tags: html, css, email, mobile

My emails look great in all browsers and mail parsers, but on the iPhone, the text is bigger than it should be.

I was thinking..is there an inline CSS for mobile that specifies the font-size attribute?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to target mobile browsers specifically?

Comment: Since they're the only ones with larger text than anyone else, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will stop the iPhone resizing your text `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;`

[This](http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails) is a great article on email design and it mentions this exact problem and solution (near the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

you could try media queries again it's a CSS3 specification so depending on the mail client rendering the email it might not render 100% correctly, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Here is some markup to get you started:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait) 
{ 
    body{background:#F0F;} 
}
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) 
{
    body{background:#F00;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) 
{ 
    body{background:#0F0;} 
}
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape) 
{ 
    body{background:#FF0;} 
}
```